# why i can have two locks( X and S) on one record in innodb? i know that S and X lock can not exists at the same time

Tags: mysql, innodb

[image: enter image description]

why i can have two locks( X and S) on one record in innodb? i know that S and X lock can not exists at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Your S lock is escalated to an X lock with these two queries executed in sequence within the same transaction.  You don't have both.

If a second transaction also obtained an S lock on the same records, and then your `FOR UPDATE` query were run, it would block at least until the other transaction made its next move, perhaps longer, until the lock escalation could occur or be determined impossibe.  Eventually the prompt would return or you'd get a deadlock.

Comment: Then can X lock is escalated to S lock?  for example, first, i excute  FOR UPDATE. after i excute a share mode query. what abou this?

Comment: X to S wouldn't be an escalation, I assume it would remain X, but I'm not sure you understand the point of my explanation, which requires two concurrent transactions on two different connections.